# Extract child elements and add parent field into them

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to combine nested arrays into a single object so that I can do some sorting. For example, I have the following

```
{
    "disk": [
        { 
            "device": "/dev/sda",
            "partitions": [
                { "type": "fat32", "mount": "/efi" },
                { "type": "ext4", "mount": "/boot" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/sdb",
            "partitions": [
                { "type": "xfs", "mount": "/" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to say 'give me all partitions where mount is not null, sort them by mount, but include their device name in the output'.

So far I have `jq -c '.disk[].partitions[] | select (.mount != null)'` which is giving me the correct partitions as such:

```json
{ "type": "xfs", "mount": "/" }
{ "type": "ext4", "mount": "/boot" }
{ "type": "fat32", "mount": "/efi" }
```

However, I would like to pull in the parent device as such:

```json
{ "type": "xfs", "mount": "/", "device": "/sdb" }
{ "type": "ext4", "mount": "/boot", "device": "/sda" }
{ "type": "fat32", "mount": "/efi", "device": "/sda" }
```

I've seen other examples that drive off the parent and then pull in the children, but it doesn't seem to work when the parent itself is an array. Is there a way to say "get a child property" such as  `... | .device = ..device`

Comment: Did you mean group by `.mount`? Trying to understand the need for sort here

Comment: I need parent directories before child directories. So I need it in the order of /, /home, /home/foo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go back one level to fetch **device**. Just get a copy of it, select **partitions**, and add them together.

```
.disk
| map((.partitions[] | select(.mount != null)) + {device})
| sort_by(.mount)[]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Sgs_dXGHuU)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can enrich the partitions with the device and filter the enriched partitions:

```
jq '.disk[]
    | .device as $d
    | .partitions[] += { device: $d }
    | .partitions[]
    | select(.mount != null)
    ' file.json
```